# Usage of javaagent with Android

Tags: java, android, jvm-arguments, design-by-contract

I've recently became interested in DBC methodology. As Java is my "native" language I've looked at [cofoja](http://code.google.com/p/cofoja/) and more recently [java-on-contracts](http://code.google.com/p/java-on-contracts/). I mainly create Android software, so naturally I'd like to be able to use contracts on my phone.

Both projects require the usage of something similar to

```
java -javaagent:path/to/cofoja-<version>.jar <someclass>
```

as JVM parameter. Is it possible to use this JVM parameter to launch apk on phone? Does dalvik even support this kind of parameters?

How could I even pass this parameter to start an application? I don't have a clue on how to start. Maybe through an ant script?

Answer (score 2):

Closest thing to javaagent on android is instrumentation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html

but I doubt cofoja wil support this out of the box. I think it would be possible to implement this but not sure whether such project already started

And here is project goung roughly in direction desired by you:

http://code.google.com/p/droidbox/

Comment: Do you know any other DBC library which I could use on android? Also the project you mention would be quite hard to use for DBC imo.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not aware of it.  My interest in android are in other areas ( dependency injection )